# Display error validation on another control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have a `TextBlock` and a `CheckBox`, as such:

```
<StackPanel >
    <TextBlock Text="Colors"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Blue, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In my model I am implementing `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and validating whether the checkbox is checked or not. If it's not checked, I'm treating it as an error:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), "CheckBoxRequired")]
    public bool Blue
    {
        get { return _blue; }
        set { _blue = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Blue)); }
    }

    public static ValidationResult CheckBoxRequired(object obj, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var model = (MyModel)context.ObjectInstance;
        if (model.Blue == false)
            return new ValidationResult("Blue required", new string[] { "Blue" });
        else
            return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    //...
    //INotifyPropertyChanged & INotifyDataErrorInfo implementations omitted
}
```

When I have `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` set to `true`, it correctly displays a red box around the `CheckBox`. It looks like this:

[image]

I do not want the red checkbox to appear. To do this, I explictly set `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` to `false`. This works fine.

What I want to do when there is an error is to display an error on the `TextBlock`, such as changing the font color of the `TextBlock`.  How can the `TextBlock` be aware of any errors present on the `CheckBox` and what is the best way of going about it?

My intended outcome would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all setting `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors`is not the right way to get rid of the red border. It will cause your data to not be validated at all. What you want is this:

```
<CheckBox Content="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding Model.Blue, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"/>
```

Secondy, to get the desired result, I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967367/wpf-chainging-another-controls-property-in-some-controls-trigger) kind of approach. You can use a Trigger to know if there is an Error in your CheckBox (the `ErrorsChanged` event and the `HasError` property should be useful here) and set the text color of your TextControl.

Here is the code to accomplish this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Color">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
          Margin="4,0"
          Content="Blue"
          IsChecked="{Binding Model.Blue}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I have posted an answer with the code that I used so that it can be referred to by anyone who might have the same question.

Comment: In order to consolidate information, I've proposed an edit to Karina's post to include the specific code you came up with.

Comment: I don't think I've seen parens used in markup extensions before, like `Path=(Validation.HasError)`. What's that for?

Answer (score 1):

With Karina K's insight I used the following code in order to achieve the desired result:

```
<TextBlock Text="Color">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
          Margin="4,0"
          Content="Blue"
          IsChecked="{Binding Model.Blue}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: In order to consolidate information, I've proposed an edit to Karina's post to include the specific code you came up with.